# adding class and removing class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have audio player and i made on button click for music to stop and play again but i want to change icon on it aswell, but i dont know how to add i class and remove it on click, thanks. Here is my code, i want to remove **fa-pause** and add **fa-play**

```js
var player = document.getElementById("player");
var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlay() {
  if (isPlaying) {
    player.pause()
  } else {
    player.play();
  }
};
player.onplaying = function() {
  isPlaying = true;
};
player.onpause = function() {
  isPlaying = false;
};
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="togglePlay()"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
```

Comment: `$(...).addClass('fa-play').removeClass('fa-pause');`

Comment: so toggleCass.....

Comment: `document.getElementById("player").classList.toggleClass( 'fa-pause', 'fa-play' )` Make sure your element is initialised with one of both or both will be applied and removed at the same time. FYI You might also want to consider getting rid of the variable `isPlaying` and just use `player.paused` directly, reducing memory for something already available.

Comment: @somethinghere - put that in an answer so I can upvote you :-)

Comment: @RandyCasburn I gave this answer because the question contains the jquery tag

Comment: @ControlAltDel - fair enough, I'll remove my comment about that then.

Comment: @somethinghere can u add code in answer im trying to do what u said , but im doing something wrong so it doesnt work, thanks

Comment: @infernalx My bad, rechecked the docs and toggling only works one class at a time, so I had to split it into two lines (one for `fa-paused` one for `fa-play`). See my answer for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add an id for your play/pause button.

```
<button id="control-btn" class="button" onclick="togglePlay()"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
```

Then select the `<i class="fas fa-pause"></i>` item and remove/add the class

```
var player = document.getElementById("player");
var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlay() {
  var item = document.querySelector("#control-btn i");
  if(isPlaying) {
    player.pause();
    item.classList.remove("fa-pause");
    item.classList.add("fa-play");
  } else {
    player.play();
    item.classList.remove("fa-play");
    item.classList.add("fa-pause");
  }
};
player.onplaying = function(){
  isPlaying = true;
};
player.onpause = function(){
  isPlaying = false;
};
```

Comment: it doesnt work i added everything u mentioned but still same

Comment: Really ? this is the code working: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQ3DKE9YXCB8

Comment: for some reason music server was down, and because that it didnt worked , no sense in my opinion , but thanks i appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. Your code contains needed few refactoring since you are using html only. I would recommend you use jquery to simplify the code.

https://jsfiddle.net/c5ystb4t/16/

code below is your sample.

```js
var player = document.getElementById("player");
var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlay() {
  if (isPlaying) {
    player.pause()
  } else {
    player.play();
  }
};
player.onplaying = function() {
  isPlaying = true;
};
player.onpause = function() {
  isPlaying = false;
};
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="togglePlay()"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `toggleClass` method from `classList`:

```
document.getElementById( 'player' ).classList.toggleClass( 'fa-pause' )
document.getElementById( 'player' ).classList.toggleClass( 'fa-play' )
```

Make sure one of both classes is already active, otherwise both will activate or deactivate at once.

**Edit** I checked the docs on toggle and you can only do one class name per call.

```js
document.getElementById( 'test' ).addEventListener('click', function( event ){
  
  event.preventDefault();
  event.target.classList.toggle( 'a' );
  event.target.classList.toggle( 'b' );
  
})
```

```css
.a { color: red !important; }
.b { color: yellow !important; }
```

```html
<a href="#" id="test" class="a">Click me to toggle Classes</a>
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

On a sidenote, you might want to get rid of your `isPlaying` variable and just use `plater.paused`, since it contains a boolean as well that you don't have to track, and therefor saves you a little bit of memory.